# Динамическое добавление колонок из массива в react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь добавить в таблицу, в которой есть постоянные колонки, новые колонки, приходящие в массиве.

```
class CampaignBargainRent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: this.props.data
    };

}

render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ReactTable
                data={data}
                columns={[
                    {
                        Header: 'name'
                        accessor: "cost",
                    },
                   ...
                    {
                        Header: 'name_n'
                        accessor: "agency_cost",
                    },



                ]}

            />
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}
}
```

data выглядит примерно таким образом

```
[{
 cost:666,

 ...
 agencycost:666,
 reserve: [
          { 
            month: name
            ...
            cost: 666
          },
          ...
          { 
            month: name,
            ...
            cost: 666
          }
          ]
}]
```

нужно динамически добавить столбцы в конец таблицы в зависимости от данных в data.reserve. Через getTrProps получается составить массивы колонок и их значений, но не могу понять как вставить в таблицу данные

```
getTrProps={(rowInfo) => {
        let arr = [];
        Object.keys(rowInfo.original.reserve).map(key => {
            arr.push({
                Header: rowInfo.original.reserve[key].month
                accessor: key,
                Cell: rowInfo.original.reserve[key].cost
            });
        });
        console.log(arr)

    return {

    }
}}
```